# Button is Pressed Before the Segue Finishes iOS + Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I am switching between view controllers by using a button, if I repeatedly press the button, the next view controller will continue to appear. I don't know what is causing the error.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64lwT9kq3khRHNtZ0d0Q1hiNEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I fixed the video so that everyone can view it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your button is still active during the *circle expand* animation, so each time you press it, another view controller is pushed on to the navigation stack. The push animations then stack up.

Try disabling the button just before triggering the animation and re-enabling it after using `button.enabled = NO;` or `button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`.

Alternatively, you can implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:` and disable the button just prior to the segue, and then re-enable the button in `-viewWillAppear:`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        self.nextButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.nextButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

To get `segue.identifier`, just click on the segue in IB and go to Attributes Inspector tab. This approach might be preferable to you if you'd rather use IB to handle segues rather than target-action on a UIControl (or UIButton in this case).